# Can't understand a matplotlib's example where there are both ellipsis and colons probably associated with indices

Tags: python, indexing, slice, ellipsis

I have a question about this **matplotlib**'s [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/animation/basic_example.html).

Here's the part that I don't understand

```
def update_line(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[...,:num])
    return line,
```

What does `line.set_data(data[...,:num])` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a special syntax provided by numpy for slicing in multidimensional arrays. The general syntax is `a[s1,s2, ... , sn]`, where `si` is the expression used for usual slicing or indexing sequences and defines desired slice in i'th dimension. For example, `a[5,2:3,1::2]`.

The `...` is the shortening for getting full slices in all dimensions. For example `a[...,3]` is the shortening for `a[:,:,3]` if `a` is three-dimensional.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually a `numpy` notation. In `numpy`, `...` (Ellipsis) is used as a placeholder for a variable number of `:` slices.

From [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> Ellipsis expand to the number of : objects needed to make a selection
>   tuple of the same length as x.ndim. Only the first ellipsis is
>   expanded, any others are interpreted as :.

Usage:

```
In : x = numpy.array(range(8)).reshape(2,2,2)

In : x
Out:
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])

In : x[...,0]
Out:
array([[0, 2],
       [4, 6]])

In : x[:,:,0]
Out:
array([[0, 2],
       [4, 6]])
```